# ODIN - Touchpad two finger scrolling hard to use

Tags: touchpad

Coming from OSX - and very frustrated at Apple due the bad quality of their recent product -, I just moved to elementary OS.

I find the touchpad two finger scrolling (killer app for me) hard to use on my HP245 G8.

- there is some kind of lag before it starts to scroll (or you can simply do a light two-finger scroll and nothing happens)
- once it start to scroll, this is way to fast.
  This is very far from the feel in OSX. I don't know how much relates to hw vs sw.

Are there any variables exposed to control this ?

Comment: I can confirm this. On Hera, everything worked fine and after replacing Hera with Odin, on the same laptop, I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are some settings available for the touchpad, though a lot of the responsiveness is controlled by the hardware itself. That said, take a look at some of the items in the Touchpad section of "Mouse & Touchpad":

[image: Mouse & Touchpad — Touchpad]

I do not have an HP nearby to test this with but, on a particularly sluggish Fujitsu, I found touch responsiveness to be better when "Ignore While Typing" was disabled. So long as your touchpad isn't as large as what one would find on a modern Apple notebook, this *may* do the trick for you. The only downside is that a random palm touch when hitting the spacebar will cause the cursor to change location ... and possibly result in some cursing.